# переход по слайдеру код написан правильно?

Tags: javascript

```js
thumbs.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;
 if( target.closest('a') ){
    // thumbs.style.ListStyleType = 'none'
   e.preventDefault();
   let s = target.closest('a')
   let href = s.getAttribute('href');
   let d = largeImg.src = href
 }
});
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 75%/120% sans-serif;
  }

  h2 {
    font: bold 190%/100% sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 .2em;
  }

  h2 em {
    font: normal 80%/100% sans-serif;
    color: #999999;
  }

  #largeImg {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 550px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  #thumbs a {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
  }

  #thumbs a:hover {
    border-color: #FF9900;
  }

#thumbs{
   list-style-type: none; 
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p><img id="largeImg" src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img1-lg.jpg" alt="Large image"></p>

  <ul id="thumbs">
    <!-- браузер показывает небольшую встроенную подсказку из атрибута "title" при наведении курсора на текст -->
    <li>
      <a href="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img2-lg.jpg" title="Image 2"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img2-thumb.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img3-lg.jpg" title="Image 3"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img3-thumb.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img4-lg.jpg" title="Image 4"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img4-thumb.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-lg.jpg" title="Image 5"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-thumb.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-lg.jpg" title="Image 6"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-thumb.jpg"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

1. Правильно сделал слайдер ?
2. В стилях есть #thumbs как *list-style-type* прописать на js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• `float` используют для обтекания текстом, не для позиционирования. Конкретно здесь, можно использовать display: flex; например.

• Ссылки `<a>` лишние, потому что единстенное что делают - хранят адрес картинки, которую надо показывать при клике. А адрес и так уже есть у `<img>` — можно клик привязать к самой картинке и сразу оттуда и доставать адрес.

• Хоть оно и понимает, что это про id, если в коде просто написать название id элемента, но это считается плохой практикой (создается глобальная переменная). В коде желательно всегда создавать переменные и сохранять туда элементы через `getElementById`.

• `thumbs.style.listStyleType` вы правильно записали, но оно лежало внутри обработчика клика и могло сработать только после клика. Нужно было вынести его оттуда.

```js
let largeImg = document.getElementById('largeImg');
let thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbs');
thumbs.style.listStyleType = "none";

thumbs.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if ( target.tagName === "IMG" ) {
    largeImg.src = target.dataset.bigImg;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 75%/120% sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font: bold 190%/100% sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 .2em;
}

h2 em {
  font: normal 80%/100% sans-serif;
  color: #999999;
}

#largeImg {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#thumbs li {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
}

#thumbs li:hover {
  border-color: #FF9900;
}

#thumbs {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p><img id="largeImg" src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img1-lg.jpg" alt="Large image"></p>

<ul id="thumbs">
  <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img2-thumb.jpg" data-big-img="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img2-lg.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img3-thumb.jpg" data-big-img="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img3-lg.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img4-thumb.jpg" data-big-img="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img4-lg.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-thumb.jpg" data-big-img="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-lg.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-thumb.jpg" data-big-img="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-lg.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1) структуры слайдера я взял от сюда https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action 2) я сперва  сделал как Вы написали через img а потом обнаружил что при клике картинки расплывчатые получается (подумал что так не правильно и сделал через тег а )

Comment: 3) лень было переписывать глобальные переменные (в учебном примере ) 4) понял свою ошибку 5) В целом спасибо

Comment: @user354190 ой, а я не заметил, что там разные картинки. Исправил на дата-атрибуты) Хотя, если получается такая стуация, что есть железобетонная уверенность, что адреса картинок будут отличаться только парой букв - можно вообще убрать атрибуты и сделать `largeImg.src = target.src.replace(/(img\d+)-thumb/, "$1-lg");` — будет работать и так) Называется "регулярное выражение".